# Netflix Ribbon: add/edit a LoadBalancerRule at runtime via Archaius

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon

My goal is to be able to add/edit a Ribbon LoadBalancerRule at runtime via Archaius.

```
myService.ribbon.NFLoadBalancerRuleClassName=com.netflix.loadbalancer.WeightedResponseTimeRule
```

I'm trying to change the property NFLoadBalancerRuleClassName at runtime  via Archaius. I see the archaius log that notifies me that the property was changed, but ribbon doesn't refresh with the new rule and still use the old rule.

> [pollingConfigurationSource] | DEBUG | com.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyUpdater | addOrChangeProperty | adding property key [myService.ribbon.NFLoadBalancerRuleClassName], value [com.netflix.loadbalancer.WeightedResponseTimeRule]

Am I missing something?

I am using the 1.2.1.RELEASE version of spring cloud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this is not supported.

See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1438